# Convert a PowerShell foreach loop to a batch file for /f loop

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Need to convert this from powershell to batch

```
$filenames = Get-Content -Path "C:\filenames.txt"
$deletePath = "C:\DeletePath"

foreach ($file in $filenames)
{
Remove-Item -Path "$deletePath\$file.*"
}
```

thanks for any help

my code

```
set /p filenames=<"C:\filenames.txt"
set deletePath="C:\DeletePath\"

for /f %%b in (%filenames%) do del %deletePath%\%%b
```

Comment: what's the reason you need to convert back to batch? Why don't just write the whole script in powershell and be future proof? or if not possible just call some powershell commands from batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "deletePath=C:\DeletePath"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\filenames.txt") do echo del "%deletePath%\%%i"
```

Remove `echo` to perform actual deletion.

*Explanation*:

- The most robust way to set a variable whose value may contain whitespace is to enclose *both* the name and the value in `"..."` (`set "deletePath=C:\DeletePath"`)
  .

  - By contrast, if you double-quoted *only* the value, the `"` become *part of* the value (`set deletePath="C:\DeletePath"`)
  - Generally, see `help set`, though the quoting issues aren't explained there.
- `for /f` can be used to loop over the lines in a file, with the double-quoted string (`"..."`) before the iteration variable (`%%i`) specifying *options* (see `help for`):

  - `usebackq` in this case enables the use of `"..."` around the input file path, without that file path getting interpreted as a *string* instead.
  - `delims=` ensures that each line is read *in full* from the input file, even if it contains whitespace.
  - By contrast, `set /p filenames=<"C:\filenames.txt"` would only read the *first* line from the specified file into variable `%filenames%`.